# C Malloc Run-time Error

Tags: c, malloc, runtime-error, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've got the following snippet of code:

```
typedef struct person {
    char *first ;
    char *last ;
    char *location ;
    struct person *next_person ;
} person ;

person *make_person(char *first, char *last, char *location) {
    person *personp = (person*) malloc(sizeof(struct person));

    personp->first = (char*) malloc(sizeof(strlen(first) + 1));
    personp->last = (char*) malloc(sizeof(strlen(last) + 1));
    personp->location = (char*) malloc(sizeof(strlen(location) + 1));

    strcpy(personp->first, first);
    strcpy(personp->last, last);
    strcpy(personp->location, location);

    personp->next_person = NULL;

    return personp ;
}
```

When I integrate it with the rest of my code, it begins executing, then proceeds go ballistic.

```
*** glibc detected *** ./level1: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0804a188 ***
```

Any idea what's going wrong? I have a feeling it has to do with my malloc.

Comment: Style: why are you explicitly casting the pointer returned from `malloc`? In C that is not necessary and can even hide problems. And what is a `song`? Where do you `free` your pointers?

Comment: Curious: Why does it hide problems? And sorry about the "song". I modified the problem and missed that. I apologize.

Comment: do not forget to check malloc successfully allocated

Comment: if you forget to include the prototype of `malloc` its return value is take as an `int` instead of `void*`. By that you may loose bytes of the returned pointer. In C, `void*` can be assigned to any other data pointer type.

Comment: in C (not C++), `void *` can be implicitly cast to any other pointer type, such as what would happen with the returned `void *` from `malloc`. If, however, types changed (like you changed the type of your pointer) but forgot to change your cast as well, you would likely suppress `incompatible type assignment` warnings. Not to mention, it's just more needless typing. :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do:

```
personp->first = (char*) malloc(sizeof(strlen(first) + 1));
```

which is incorrect. You should not be using `sizeof` the way you've used. You need:

```
personp->first = malloc(strlen(first) + 1);
```

Comment: Oh good catch, I glossed over that. It seems like he's just really lucky this didn't blow up in `make_person` as it seems like he only gets problems during `free`. Still don't have to do an explicit pointer cast from `void*` returned by `malloc` in C, though. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Why are you casting a person into a song?

```
person *personp = (song*) malloc(sizeof(struct person));
```

Answer (score 1):

And btw there is a function to do what you want to do, it's `strdup` it's not in the C standard but is nearly everywhere, and can eventually be implemented in a 2 liner if it is not.

```
person *make_person(const char *first, const char *last, const char *location) {
  person *personp = malloc(sizeof(struct person));

  personp->first       = strdup(first); 
  personp->last        = strdup(last);
  personp->location    = strdup(location);
  personp->next_person = NULL;

  return personp ;
}
```

EDIT: I added also `const` qualifiers to the signature of the function, as the strings passed are only read and not modified. This gives a little more information to the programmer who will use that function in the future. He will know that he can pass safely his buffers and constant strings without worrying that the function might blow up.

Answer (score 0):

cast to `person`

```
person *personp = (person *) malloc(sizeof(struct person));
```

do not do `sizeof`

```
personp->first = (char*) malloc(strlen(first) + 1);
personp->last = (char*) malloc(strlen(last) + 1);
personp->location = (char*) malloc(strlen(location) + 1);
```

You also need to check `malloc` was successful